# Desktop software for tracking domain and hostings

Tags: hosting

Being a small hosting (~250 domain) company owner, I'm looking for a **desktop** software for tracking my domains and hosts. Perhaps something like AWBS for windows. Integration with plesk server is big plus. If there isn't such software, what web based free solution would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of any native Windows apps for what you want but there is this web app:
[Domain Name Portfolio](http://www.domainportfolio.us/)
Their is a demo on the site to try it out.
I have never used it I just know of it's existence.

Answer (score 1):

[DNZoom](http://www.dnzoom.com/) is another web app which does just that...

Also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/20523/tips-for-domain-name-management) might be of interest.